# Create new web app offline c# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, offline

I notice (beginner) that when I generate a new .net web app in Visual Studio, it collects required packages from the web. I believe I need to connected to the web in order to create an app. Is there an offline mode where it stores the files needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new project, Visual studio will download the require NuGet packages (=dependencies) from the internet.

Technically you can add a local NuGet repository (=on your hard drive) but do you really want to do that?!

I found this article describing how to achieve that [src](https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/)

Comment: thanks, thinking about it ruby and js download packages too - I just didn't think of it in the same way as .net